# Python Web Scraping Using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

Website to scrape
https://idaman.kpkt.gov.my/idv5xe/98_eHome/maklumatProjek.cfm?pmju_kod=8898&proj_kod_Fasa=1

Item to scrape in BOLD - Part 1 (HTML Below)

```html
<form onsubmit="return lucee_form_c9u.check();" name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="mPPTProjek3.cfm?mn=BPPT" method="post">
    <div align="center" style="background-color: white; border: 1px solid grey;">
        <br />
        <table class="MainContent" width="100%" align="center">
            <tbody>
                <tr style="font-weight: bold;">
                    <td class="column" width="30%">Nama Pemaju</td>
                    <td>
                        :
                        <a style="color: blue;" href="maklumatPemaju.cfm?pmju_Kod=8877">**RAPID UNITY SDN. BHD.**</a>
                        <font color="red">* Klik Untuk Melihat Maklumat</font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="column">Kod Pemaju</td>
                    <td>: **8877<**/td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="column">Kod Fasa</td>
                    <td>: **1<**/td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="column">Nama Pemajuan</td>
                    <td>: **TAMAN UNITY**</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Item to scrape in BOLD - Part 2

This code required selenium driver to click on the link

1. `<tr align="center" onclick="change3('15536',this)" style="cursor:pointer" bgcolor="DAEEF3" onmouseover="this.bgColor='#FF9900'" onmouseout="this.bgColor='DAEEF3'">`

then only the 95% after "name:myForm" will appear`

2. `<tr align="center" onclick="change3('15536',this)" style="cursor:pointer" bgcolor="DAEEF3" onmouseover="this.bgColor='#FF9900'" onmouseout="this.bgColor='DAEEF3'">`

then the 95% will change to other amount

(HTML Below)

```html
<fieldset title="Maklumat Pemajuan Projek" style="border: 1px solid grey; font-weight: bold; color: black;">
    <legend>Maklumat Pemajuan Projek</legend>
    <table class="MainContent" width="100%" align="center">
        <thead>
            <tr class="column">
                <th>Bil</th>
                <th>Bil Unit</th>
                <th>
                    Jenis<br />
                    Rumah
                </th>
                <th>
                    Kategori<br />
                    Rumah
                </th>
                <th>Tingkat</th>
                <th>
                    Harga<br />
                    Min (RM)
                </th>
                <th>
                    Harga<br />
                    Max (RM)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr align="center" onclick="change2('15535',this)" style="cursor: pointer;" bgcolor="white" onmouseover="this.bgColor='#FF9900'" onmouseout="this.bgColor='white'">
                <td>**1**</td>
                <td>**2**</td>
                <td align="left">
                    **RUMAH BERKEMBAR**
                </td>
                <td>
                    **HARGA TINGGI**
                </td>
                <td>**1**</td>
                <td align="right">**370,000.00**</td>
                <td align="right">**394,900.00**</td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center" onclick="change3('15536',this)" style="cursor: pointer;" bgcolor="DAEEF3" onmouseover="this.bgColor='#FF9900'" onmouseout="this.bgColor='DAEEF3'">
                <td>**2**</td>
                <td>**18**</td>
                <td align="left">
                    **RUMAH TERES**
                </td>
                <td>
                    **HARGA TINGGI**
                </td>
                <td>**1**</td>
                <td align="right">**190,000.00**</td>
                <td align="right">**290,550.00**</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
    <input name="rekid3" id="rekid3" type="hidden" value="15535" />
    <div id="pemajuan">
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/lucee/formtag-form.cfm"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            function _CF_checkmyForm() {
                return lucee_form_czz.check();
            }
        </script>
        <table class="MainContent" width="100%" align="center">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="column" width="30%">Jenis Rumah</td>
                    <td>: RUMAH BERKEMBAR</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="column">Kategori Rumah</td>
                    <td>: HARGA TINGGI</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="column">Bil Tingkat</td>
                    <td>: 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="column">Bil Unit</td>
                    <td>: 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="column">Harga Minimum</td>
                    <td>: 370,000.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="column">Harga Maximum</td>
                    <td>: 394,900.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="column">Peratusan Pemajuan</td>
                    <td>: **95%**</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- name:myForm -->
        <script>
            lucee_form_czz = new LuceeForms("myForm", null);
        </script>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

The below is the code and believe me, is all I can write after weeks....please help me as I do not know how to

1. Scrape part 1 then
2. Click the 1st link in part 2 then
3. Scrape part 2 then
4. Click the 2nd link in part 2 then
5. Scrape part 2 and append.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    
url = "https://idaman.kpkt.gov.my/idv5xe/98_eHome/maklumatProjek.cfm?pmju_kod=8898&proj_kod_Fasa=1"
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/freddielee/Downloads/chromedriver')

driver.find_element(By.NAME="need help here")
```

Comment: What can't you do? The scraping part or the click?

Comment: At which step are you stuck exactly?

Comment: the scraping part I can't locate the element and the click also couldn't find the element to click

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want can be obtained just using `requests` and `beautifulsoup` as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()

params = {"pmju_Kod" : 8877, "proj_Kod_Fasa" : 1}
r = s.get("https://idaman.kpkt.gov.my/idv5xe/98_eHome/maklumatProjek.cfm", params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

tables = soup.find_all('table', class_="MainContent")

items = []

items.append(tables[0].a.text)

data = [[td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')] for tr in tables[0].find_all('tr')]
items.append(data[1][1].strip(': '))
items.append(data[2][1].strip(': '))
items.append(data[3][1].strip(': '))

data = [[td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')] for tr in tables[3].find_all('tr')]

items.append(data[1][2].strip())
items.append(data[1][3].strip())
items.append(data[1][4])
items.append(data[1][5])
items.append(data[1][6])

items.append(data[2][2].strip())
items.append(data[2][3].strip())
items.append(data[2][4])
items.append(data[2][5])
items.append(data[2][6])

# Pemajuan table
params['rekid'] = 419975503
r2 = s.get('https://idaman.kpkt.gov.my/idv5xe/98_eHome/template/pemajuan.cfm', params=params)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.content, "html.parser")
table = soup2.find('table', class_="MainContent")
data = [[td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')] for tr in table.find_all('tr')]
items.append(data[-1][1].strip(': '))

print(items)
```

This would give you the following items:

```
['RAPID UNITY SDN. BHD.', '8877', '1', 'TAMAN UNITY', 'RUMAH BERKEMBAR', 'HARGA TINGGI', '1', '370,000.00', '394,900.00', 'RUMAH TERES', 'HARGA TINGGI', '1', '190,000.00', '290,550.00', '0%']
```

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your input and guidance. How about the last item as below <br>                 <tr>
                    <td class="column">Peratusan Pemajuan</td>
                    <td>: **95%**</td>

Comment: That table is obtained via a second request, I have updated to show you how

Comment: Hi Martin, apologies for having some ambiguity in my question. for the second request, actually there are shadow content (user agent) after the "rekid". The content required a click onto table3, Data[1][2] to reveal additional data for data [1][2] and another click onto table3,, data[2][2] to reveal the additional data for data [2][2]. secondly, if I have a list of 10 params under first request, how can I create a loop? for r2, can I use soup to find rekid?

Comment: Have you tried using your browser's network tools to watch the requests. This is how I was able to build this script.  Watch what happens when clicking on items. Use it to view headers and parameters.  The id is probably there somewhere to use